# Azure devops pipeline ArchiveFiles error: Unable to locate executable file: 'zip'

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm creating an Azure DevOps pipeline for python package build, but the task ArchiveFiles@2 failed.

```
- stage: Build
  jobs:
    - job: BuildApp
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      - task: ArchiveFiles@2
        inputs:
          rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
          includeRootFolder: false
          archiveType: 'zip'
          archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
          replaceExistingArchive: true
          verbose: true
```

The error log is this

```
Found 20 files
Archiving file: .env_sample
... 21 more ...

##[debug]Checking for archive destination folder:/__w/1/a
##[debug]Creating archive with zip: /__w/1/a/1009007.zip
##[debug]which 'zip'
##[debug]not found
##[debug]Unable to locate executable file: 'zip'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
```

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Yes, I still have the issue. From the answer I got it should work with Ubuntu latest version, but I'm not sure why it didn't work in my case.

Comment: Hi @CPP_atheitia, could you check your org region and then share it here? In addition, could you try to create another region org and test it again?

Comment: @Carlos hi, the region is West Europe

Answer (score 8):

The agent doesn't have the `zip` command installed on it. You'll need to make sure the `zip` package is installed. i.e. `sudo apt-get -y install zip`

Answer (score 0):

The agent ubuntu-latest is Ubuntu20.04, it has install `zip 3.0` and `7-Zip 16.02`, we could check this [doc](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-README.md#tools) for more details.

You could try this yaml, I tested it and it works.

YAML definition:

```
trigger: none
stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: BuildApp
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
        - task: ArchiveFiles@2
          inputs:
            rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
            includeRootFolder: false
            archiveType: 'zip'
            archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
            replaceExistingArchive: true
            verbose: true
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using 7z to produce a zip file. The following works for us on ubuntu:

```
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(APP_DIST_DIR)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: '7z'
        archiveFile: '$(APP_DIST_DIR)/myfilename.zip'
        replaceExistingArchive: true
```