# Azure Pipeline Extract Task 7zip

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, task

Unable to extract zip to destination with default usage of [Extract Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/extract-files?view=azure-devops) its fails with error:

```
##[error]Unable to locate executable file: 'C:\azagent\A5\_work\_tasks\ExtractFiles_5e1e3830-fbfb-11e5-aab1-090c92bc4988\1.200.0\7zip\7z.exe'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable file.
```

Stating its fails to locate default 7zip path. Tried to use custom PATH setting but also fails with the same error.

**UPDATE**

Issue seem to be caused by permissions of agent. Still haven't been able to execute Release with Admin privileges in service mode. When run in interactive mode as Admin the release executes successfully.

Task fails whenever admin permission is required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure devops pipeline ArchiveFiles error: Unable to locate executable file: 'zip'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66384704/azure-devops-pipeline-archivefiles-error-unable-to-locate-executable-file-zip)

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, 7zip seems not installed on your self-hosted agent. Try to install the 7zip before you use the Extract Task.

Take Bash Task as an example:

```
brew install p7zip
```

For Windows, use the below PowerShell script to install:

```
$dlurl = 'https://7-zip.org/' + (Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri 'https://7-zip.org/' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Links | Where-Object {($_.outerHTML -match 'Download')-and ($_.href -like "a/*") -and ($_.href -like "*-x64.exe")} | Select-Object -First 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty href)
# modified to work without IE
# above code from: https://perplexity.nl/windows-powershell/installing-or-updating-7-zip-using-powershell/
$installerPath = Join-Path $env:TEMP (Split-Path $dlurl -Leaf)
Invoke-WebRequest $dlurl -OutFile $installerPath
Start-Process -FilePath $installerPath -Args "/S" -Verb RunAs -Wait
Remove-Item $installerPath
```